# Why does integration variable change?

Tags: integration, physics

This is probably a very stupid question but I came across the following in an electrical engineering textbook

[image]

Here is what I did:
[image]

**I am wondering, in Eq 6.5, why have function of current changed from being a vairbale of t to a variable of tau? And also in Eq 6.6, where is the v(t0) coming from?**

Again, I apologise if this is really basic, but I haven't done integration problems in years and I couldn't find anything talking specifically about variable changes.

Comment: $\tau$ is a dummy variable, it doesn't matter what you name as it goes away :  $$v(t) = \frac{1}{C}\int\limits_{\tau =-\infty}^{\tau = t}i(\tau)d\tau$$

Comment: as an example, let $i(t) = e^{t}$ and  try working  $$v(t) =\frac{1}{C}\int\limits_{\tau =-\infty}^{\tau = t}i(\tau)d\tau =  \frac{1}{C}\int\limits_{\tau =-\infty}^{\tau = t}e^{\tau}~d\tau = ?$$

Comment: Re-write 6.6 as $v(t)-v(t_0)=(1/C)\int_{i_0}^ti(\tau)d\tau. $ This holds for any continuous function  $i$  if $dv(t)/dt=i(t)/C.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2.$ The constant of integration $\displaystyle v(t_0)=\frac1C\int_{-\infty}^0i\;$ is the voltage that the capacitor had started with at arbitrary time $t_0.$

$1.$ Notice that my integral in point 2 above has neither $\mathrm dt$ nor $\mathrm d\tau?$ That's because they are just dummy variables (here understood to be representing time), and dropping the integration variable here in favour of a succinct notation loses no generality.$\quad$In Eqn 6.5, the author had switched the integration variable from $\color{#00F}t$ to $\color{#00F}\tau$ (any dummy variable will do, since it doesn't explicitly appear in the integrand) in order to distinguish the integration variable from the upper limit of integration $\color{#C00}t$ (i.e., the $\color{#C00}t$ in the interval of integration $[-\infty,\color{#C00}t]$).

(Check out [the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part); similarly as above, because $\color{#C00}x$ is already the upper limit of integration, $\color{#00F}t$ is instead chosen as the variable of integration.)

Comment: Oh I see. If we integrate between the limits of - infinity and 0, then we don't need to take the initial voltage into account since v(-infinity) = 0, but if start at an arbitrary t0, we have to account for the voltage at that time. -

Comment: And for the variable, since when we evaluate the integral, we'll just be substituting in time values anyways, it's essentially doesn't matter.